# How can I interact with shell responses with .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a CLI app to hide some of the details of running commands in the shell/terminal.

With the code below I can execute a single command `ssh`, for example:

```cs
var result = RunCommand("ssh", "100.100.109.86");

static string RunCommand(string command, string args)
{
    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    

    var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? output : error;
}
```

My question is how can implement a loop so that I can output the result of the command to the user and enable them to execute another command (or more)?

For example, the response to the above `ssh` command might as the to ask them if they are sure they want to connect inviting them to respond with `(yes/no/[fingerprint])`

Comment: There is a very good library called [cliwrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) you can checkout its source code for some tips.

Comment: cliwrap is very good. If you are doing ssh specifically, consider using an ssh library for .net

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually looking to implement this around `sshuttle`. I'll update my post